# Which files do get_user() require on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function, cron-task

I need to run a cron job on a wordpress site which in the script includes the function get_users() however because this script is a single file it does not include any of the core wordpress files.

My question is which files do I need to include in order for the get_users() function to run.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Best regards

David

Answer (score 5):

You need to require `wp-load.php` file. Include following code in the beginning of your file:

```
$path  = '';
if(!defined('WP_LOAD_PATH')){
    $root = dirname(__FILE__).'/';

    if(file_exists($root.'wp-load.php')){
        define('WP_LOAD_PATH',$root);
    }else{
        if(file_exists($path.'wp-load.php')){
            define('WP_LOAD_PATH',$path);
        }else{
            exit("Cannot find wp-load.php");
        }
    }
}
require_once(WP_LOAD_PATH.'wp-load.php');
```

Comment: Thank you and this will load all standard wordpress scripts and functions?

Comment: Yes, it will, take a look please at the file `wp-load.php`.

Comment: The above does not seem to exist do I have to pre-define $root?

Comment: Isn't your file located at the root?

Comment: Yes but the above does not seem to correctly load the file does $path need to be defined? Thanks for your help btw

Comment: Yes, you are right! I missed it. See my updated answer.

Comment: `$path  = '';` in case file located at the root.

Comment: It still doesnt seem to work and when trying to echo this in order to test its correct It only returns /wp-load.php

Comment: I have just tested it from my end and it worked. Created file `test.php` at the root folder, added above mentioned code, and called `get_users()` function, it worked properly. Could you specify which particular part is not working?

Comment: Aaaa ok it might be because my cron file is not running from the root, thanks again for all your help

Comment: Thanks so much it works perfectly, I really appreciate the help :D